# Type submit on enter press is not working in react-phone-input-international

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui, react-phone-number-input, react-phone-input-2

I am using PhoneInput from react-phone-input-international, and formik for form builder, and when i am trying to use type submit on enter press, it is not working.
Here is my code

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
    <PhoneInput
        name="mobileNumber"
        country={'in'}
        value={formik.values.mobileNumber}
        placeholder=""
        countryCodeEditable={false}
        onChange={(value, country, e, formattedValue) => {
            formik.setValues({
                ...formik.values,
                "mobileNumber": formattedValue && formattedValue.replace(/ /g, '')
            })
        }
        }
    />
    <Box className="send-otp">
        <Button
            otpBtn
            type='submit'
            name={(t(`btn.send_otp`))}
        />
    </Box>
</form>
```

I am trying type submit on button but not working.
Here is codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/phoneinput-react-gybgzd

Comment: Hello. Why don't you pass the handle submit to the button?

Comment: Doing the same still not working.

Comment: then, please show the code of the component Button to understand what's under that component

Comment: for now i am not using button component, i am using html button.
You can go through this url 
https://codesandbox.io/s/phoneinput-react-gybgzd

Comment: In the codesanbox is working

Comment: But type submit on enter press is not working

Comment: It is printing the console log

Comment: Are you trying with button click, or by pressing enter button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is to add another event

```
    <PhoneInput
        name="mobileNumber"
        country={"in"}
        value={formik.values.mobileNumber}
        style={{ width: "unset" }}
        placeholder=""
        onEnterKeyPress={()=>handleSubmit(formik.values)} // <-- here
        countryCodeEditable={false}
        onChange={(value, country, e, formattedValue) => {
          formik.setValues({
            ...formik.values,
            mobileNumber: formattedValue && formattedValue.replace(/ /g, "")
          });
        }}
      />
```